# File compressed with tar gzip or zip has slightly the same size

Tags: zip, debian, compression, gzip, bzip2

I tried to compress the same file with different compression type :

```
tar cjf dump.sql.tar.bz dump.sql
tar czf dump.sql.tar.gz dump.sql
zip -r dump.sql.zip dump.sql
```

results :

```
size     file
79968725 dump.sql            ~77MB
 9846256 dump.sql.tar.bz     ~9.4MB
13863797 dump.sql.tar.gz     ~14MB
13863826 dump.sql.zip        ~14MB
```

The best compression comes with bzip2 file. Anyway, the original file was compressed with bzip2 but its size was around 7.7MB. How to get this level of compression ?

Is there some other compression types/options to get better performances ?

Also, why the gzipped file has slightly the same size as the zipped file ? I thought gzip had a better compression rate than zip. Am I missing something ?

Any tips/hints are welcomes and will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much every compressor out there (it's the case for gz, bz2, zip and xz) lets you choose the compression level (usually from 1 to 9 for instance). The faster it compresses, the lowest the compression ratio. The slower it is, the better compression you get.
The best lossless compressor I know of is xz. It should give you better compression than bz2:

`vfcJ dump.sql.tar.xz dump.sql`

What file size do you get with this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The size is 7.7MB. Didn't know `xz` compression. I will dig about it.

Comment: For the highest compression level with xz use this: `tar cvf - dump.sql | xz -9 -e - > dump.sql.tar.xz`