# Compress .npy data to save space in disk

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, save, diskspace

l have stored on my disk a huge dataset. Since my dataset is about 1.5 TB. l divide it into 32 samples to be able to use  `numpy.save('data_1.npy')` in python 2.7 . Here is a sample of 9 sub-datasets. Each one is about 30 GB.

The shape of each `.npy` file is `(number_of_examples,224,224,19`) and values are float.

```
data_1.npy
data_2.npy
data_3.npy
data_4.npy
data_5.npy
data_6.npy
data_7.npy
data_8.npy
data_9.npy
```

Using np.save(' *.npy'), my dataset occupy 1.5 Tera in my disk.

1)Is there an efficient way to compress my dataset in order to gain some free space disk ?
2) Is there an efficient way of saving files which take less space memory than np.save() ?

Thank you

Comment: There is [savez_compressed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed). But maybe you should drop numpy's functions and go for hdf5 (e.g. pytables). With that, you should have more control over various internals (filters, compression, chunk-sizes). Additionally you can read slices out on demand (well, that's probably also possible with numpy's memmap).

Comment: @sascha, using savez_compressed/hdf5 allows to reduce drastically the space occupied on the disk ? from 1.5 T to some GB ?

Comment: `savez_compressed` creates a compressed `zip` archive. Other SO questions indicates that it creates the full size archive and then compresses it.

Comment: @ericlardon This is the typical novice-question in compression. It depends on the data. Theory forbids the existence of a compressor for random-data for example. Compression depends on your data (e.g. noise-ratio) and the compression-alg used. A bit of research and you can see what options are there (more for hdf5). 1.5 TB sometimes can be compressed to 1 byte; sometimes to 1.5TB. If compression is that important to you, look at the bigger picture. If those are jpg's, store the jpg's and not pixel-data. If already pixel-based; you can compress with png and store this in binary form.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out xz compression mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140416/14198187). I've found it to be the best compression method while saving hundreds of thousands of .npy files adding up to a few hundred GB. The shell command for a directory called `dataset` containing your `.npy` files would be:

```
tar -vfcJ dataset.tar.xz dataset/
```

This is just to save disk space while storing and moving the dataset; it needs to be decompressed before loading into python.